# How do I make an AI move in a human-like way

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, p5.js

```
var playerX;
var playerY;
var playerSize = 15;
var playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10;
var Newcelltimer = 0;
var cell = []
var cellEaten = 0;
var celliseaten = false;
var eaten = false;
var zoom = 1;
var n = 0;
var Xgrid = 600;
var Ygrid = 600;
var cpu = [];

function setup() {
  frameRate(999)
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  playerX = Xgrid / 2
  playerY = Ygrid / 2;

}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  push();
  var Newzoom = 10 / playerSize
  let newnewZoom = 1.3 * lerp(0.9, 10 / playerSize, 0.5)
  Newzoom = lerp(zoom, Newzoom, 0.3)
  translate(Xgrid / 2, Ygrid / 2 - 50);
  scale(newnewZoom)
  translate(-playerX, -playerY);


  playerSpeed = (playerSize / Math.pow(playerSize, 1.44)) * 10

  Newcelltimer++;

  for (var i = 0; i < cell.length / 2; i++) {
    let d = int(dist(cell[i * 2], cell[i * 2 + 1], playerX, playerY))
    if (d <= playerSize / 2) {
      playerSize += 5;
      cell.splice(i * 2, 2)
      celliseaten = true;
    }
  }
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    playerY -= playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    playerY += playerSpeed;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }

  if (playerX < playerSize / 2 - Xgrid) {
    playerX = playerSize / 2 - Xgrid
  }

  if (playerY < playerSize / 2 - Ygrid) {
    playerY = playerSize / 2 - Ygrid
  }

  if (playerY > 2 * Ygrid - (playerSize / 2)) {
    playerY = 2 * Ygrid - (playerSize / 2)
  }
  if (playerX > 2 * Xgrid - (playerSize / 2)) {
    playerX = 2 * Xgrid - (playerSize / 2)
  }

  if (Newcelltimer % 30 == 0) {
    cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
      ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
  }

  if (Newcelltimer % 100 == 0) {
    cpu.push(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid), random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid), 20)
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < cpu.length / 3; j++) {
    fill(0, 255, 0, 100);
    circle(NewposX,NewposY, cpu[j * 3 + 2])
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < cell.length / 2; k++) {

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    circle(cell[k * 2], cell[k * 2 + 1], 7)
  }

  stroke(0)
  fill(255,255,0)
  circle(playerX,playerY,playerSize);

  if (playerSize >= 3 * Xgrid | playerSize >= 3 * Ygrid) {
    if (Xgrid > Ygrid) {
      playerSize = 3 * Ygrid;
    } else {
      playerSize = 3 * Xgrid;
    }

  }
  noFill();
  stroke(0, 0, 0)
  rect(0 - Xgrid, 0 - Ygrid, 3 * Xgrid, 3 * Ygrid)
  pop();
  text("Your size is " + playerSize, 20, 20);
}
```

How would I make the programmed unit move in a human-like way, right now, I'm stuck on getting it to move, a way I thought was to use `Perlin` noise, but that may keep on forcing it to always go one direction, I could use random, and map out that value to `degrees/radians`, then use `trigonometry` to find the path. Although if I'm not sure what the `trigonometry` solution would be.

EDIT: When I say "In a more human-like way," I'm not talking about really anything complicated, just that the AI for example doesn't move like: Right,Left,Right,Up,Down,Left

Comment: "Getting AI to move in a human like way" is probably the most talked about problem in video game AI development. I would recommend looking for a GDC talk, I'm sure there are a few on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something move like a human is a pretty complicated task! I understand you merely wish to give some movement a natural appearance. P5’s noise function is the easiest way to achieve this.

P5’s noise function returns a float between 0 and 1, which, if directly applied to an objects position, can only move it in a positive direction. Try using the map function to normalize this output to -1 and 1 instead:

```js
map(noise(x, y, z), 0, 1, -1, 1)
```

Apply this to some kind of transformation and your agent will move in both positive and negative directions.

To displace an agent on the x-axis, therefore, you could do something along these lines:

```js
let amp = 20; // how much you want the agent to move
let offsetX = map(noise, 0, 1, -1, 1) * amp;
ellipse(200 + offsetX, 200, 10, 10);
```

Comment: There's a problem where because it's 200+offsetX, then it gets reset every frame.

Comment: Should the agent be autonomous or controlled by the player?

Comment: There's obviously the one the player controls which is yellow, and the green one is supposed to be autonomous.

Comment: It's not obvious if your game crashes before anything appears on screen…

Comment: Oh, firstly sorry if that sounded rude. Secondly, I'm not sure why it crashes on the screen, perhaps something to do with Stackoverflow, because it works in the web editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a bit vague but it sounds like what you want to do is give the AI a goal I.E. some location in which it wants to go to and then use a simple pathfinder program to let it figure out the best direction to move in

Comment: It seems your brand new to Stack Overflow, so it's all right, but this comment shouldn't be under answers, but rather the comment section.